# PyQt5 pyqtSlot decorator caused TypeError:decorated slot has no signature compatible with downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)

Tags: python, pyqt5

**PyQt5 version**:5.15.9
**Python version**:3.8
**Envior**:window 7

A simple implementation of a network downloader, but encountered some problems. code show as below:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget,
    QApplication,
    QMessageBox,
    QLineEdit,
    QProgressBar,
    QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QStyle,
    QFileDialog,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStandardPaths, QUrl, QFile, QSaveFile, QDir, QIODevice, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import qApp
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager
import sys


class DownloaderWidget(QWidget):
    """A widget to download a http file to a destination file"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self.link_box = QLineEdit()
        self.dest_box = QLineEdit()
        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.abort_button = QPushButton("Abort")

        self.link_box.setPlaceholderText("Download Link ...")

        self._open_folder_action = self.dest_box.addAction(
            qApp.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon), QLineEdit.TrailingPosition
        )
        self._open_folder_action.triggered.connect(self.on_open_folder)

        # Current QFile
        self.file = None
        # Current QNetworkReply
        self.reply = None

        # Default http url
        self.link_box.setText(
            "http://master.qt.io/archive/qt/6.0/6.0.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.0.1.zip"
        )

        # Default destination dir
        self.dest_box.setText(
            QDir.fromNativeSeparators(
                QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.DownloadLocation)
            )
        )

        # buttons bar layout
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addStretch()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.abort_button)

        # main layout
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.link_box)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.dest_box)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
        vlayout.addStretch()
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)

        self.resize(300, 100)

        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.abort_button.clicked.connect(self.on_abort)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_start(self):
        """When user press start button"""

        # http file
        url_file = QUrl(self.link_box.text())

        # destination file
        dest_path = QDir.fromNativeSeparators(self.dest_box.text().strip())
        dest_file = QDir(dest_path).filePath(url_file.fileName())

        # Ask a question if file already exists
        if QFile.exists(dest_file):
            ret = QMessageBox.question(
                self,
                "File exists",
                "Do you want to override the file ?",
                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
            )
            if ret == QMessageBox.No:
                return

            QFile.remove(dest_file)

        self.start_button.setDisabled(True)
        # Create the file in write mode to append bytes
        self.file = QSaveFile(dest_file)

        try:
            if self.file.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly):
                self.reply = self.manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url_file))
                print(f"signal:{self.reply.downloadProgress.signal}")
                self.reply.downloadProgress.connect(self.on_progress)
                self.reply.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
                self.reply.readyRead.connect(self.on_ready_read)
                self.reply.errorOccurred.connect(self.on_error)
            else:
                error = self.file.errorString()
                print(f"Cannot open device: {error}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_abort(self):
        """When user press abort button"""
        if self.reply:
            self.reply.abort()
            self.progress_bar.setValue(0)

        if self.file:
            self.file.cancelWriting()

        self.start_button.setDisabled(False)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_ready_read(self):
        """ Get available bytes and store them into the file"""
        if self.reply:
            if self.reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
                self.file.write(self.reply.readAll())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        """ Delete reply and close the file"""
        if self.reply:
            self.reply.deleteLater()

        if self.file:
            self.file.commit()

        self.start_button.setDisabled(False)

    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def on_progress(self, bytesReceived: int, bytesTotal: int):
        """ Update progress bar"""
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, bytesTotal)
        self.progress_bar.setValue(bytesReceived)

    @pyqtSlot(QNetworkReply.NetworkError)
    def on_error(self, code: QNetworkReply.NetworkError):
        """ Show a message if an error happen """
        if self.reply:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error Occurred", self.reply.errorString())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_open_folder(self):

        dir_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Open Directory", QDir.homePath(), QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        )

        if dir_path:
            dest_dir = QDir(dir_path)
            self.dest_box.setText(QDir.fromNativeSeparators(dest_dir.path()))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = DownloaderWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

click `start_button` caused an exception:
`TypeError('decorated slot has no signature compatible with downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)')`

`self.reply.downloadProgress.signal` is `2downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)`, but in the class `QNetworkReply`

```py
    def downloadProgress(self, bytesReceived, bytesTotal): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ downloadProgress(self, bytesReceived: int, bytesTotal: int) [signal] """
        pass
```

But querying PyQt5 documentation has no qint64 type, and why the downloadProgress returned signal is (qint64,qint64) not (int, int), inconsistent with the documentation?
How to make changes to fix this problem?

Comment: Try without the decorator. Just remove the whole thing and connect the regular method

Comment: The error comes from the type checking enforced by the PyQt connection, which attempts to make type conversions between Python and C++: quint64 is not just like a normal Python int, it's an unsigned long. Besides, you're overusing the slot decorator, and for absolutely no requirement. 99% of the times it's unnecessary, so, just remove all of them. OTOH, as the [documentation explains](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator), you can use strings as descriptors for types unavailable on Python: instead of `int`, use `'quint64'` (note the quotes).